# Scala/Play: Assigning a value that's not there yet

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Say I have something like this:

```
case class User(id:Option[Long], name: String)

case class Account(id:Option[Long], userId: Long)

object Account {
    // apply method
    def apply(i: Identity): Account = {
        Account(None,SomeFutureUserId)
    }
}
```

This isn't working for some reason:

`Account = Account(None,SomeUser.id)`

How would I let Play! know that there will be a `Long` type in place of `id`? Something like a placeholder?

Comment: I am sorry, but the questions is unclear

Comment: @Jatin sorry, please see my edit

Comment: Please tell very precisely what you expect but what happens instead. Or what error messages you get.

Comment: @cvogt Sorry, typo on my part.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
case class User(id:Option[Long], name: String)

case class Account(id:Option[Long], userId: Option[Long])

object Account {
    // apply method
    def apply(i: Identity): Account = {
        Account(None,None)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. This seemed to work but I'm running into a few problems. Please see my edit